# Connecting ROS and the Amazon Echo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'd like to be able to tell my Amazon Echo the name of a location in my apartment as a goal for my robot to go to.
How would you recommend I proceed, knowing that the Alexa skill will run as an Amazon Lambda function?
Precisely, how to connect my computer running ROS with the Amazon Lambda function, any idea? (Robotics is a hobby for me, I'm not a CS magician, my robot is running ROS Indigo and the navigation stack)

Thanks for the help!

Olivier

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225691/connecting-ros-and-the-amazon-echo/) by [OlivierL](https://answers.ros.org/users/19636/olivierl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might find [this](https://github.com/h2r/rosTalker) useful 
The accompanying demo is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvlq210yIp4)

---

Originally posted by [tradeA](https://answers.ros.org/users/28971/tradea/) with karma: 36 on 2017-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0